# setting a schema search_path in PostgreSQL does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have set the search path for schema TEST1 by running the following instructions, I have created user with the same name 'TEST1'

```
CREATE SCHEMA "TEST1";
SET SEARCH_PATH = "TEST1"
ALTER DATABASE edb SET SEARCH_PATH = "TEST1";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ""TEST1" to "TEST1";
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA "TEST1" TO "TEST1";
```

when i run show search_path it shows the search path but when i run select current_schema::regnamespace it throws an error.
ERROR:  schema "test1" does not exist

Comment: `select quote_ident(current_schema)::regnamespace;` Since the schema name is upper case you need to use `quote_ident()` to properly quote it to prevent the name from being down cased to `test1`. An example of why it is a good idea to stick to lower case names.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names